# In mercurial how do I bundle my latest commits and mark them as already bundled

Tags: email, version-control, mercurial, backup, bundle

From a Mercurial repository I want to regularly create a bundle with all my latest commits (in order to email them).

Starting with a clean directory I envision a process like this:

1. create a clean repository
   work on my directory
   commit
   work more in directory
   commit
   ...
2. send a bundle with the commits.
3. work on my directory
   commit
   work more in directory
   commit
   ...
4. send a bundle with the all commits **after the last sent bundle**.
5. go back to 2.

How can I do this? **The problem is step 4.** Is there a way to mark all bundled commits (in order to not bundle them again)?

---

Note: Together all the bundles I sent per email should make up the complete directory in its current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism for this in Mercurial. What you want to do is to specify the correct base changeset when you generate a new bundle. That is, in Step 4, you want to run

```
$ hg bundle --base head-used-in-step-2 changes-after-2.hg
```

You can do the bookkeeping in different ways: teach your parrot to remember the last bundled commit, write it on a post-it note, write the commit into an untracked file in the repository, or track it using a local tag.

Using a local tag is probably the best way. After you create a new bundle you move the tag to the working copy parent revsion:

```
$ hg bundle --base last-bundle
$ hg tag --local -f last-bundle
```

You need `-f` since you will be moving the tag. You wont have the `last-bundle` tag the first time you bundle, so just use `hg bundle --all` the first time.

Comment: Maybe bookmark, not tag? Inactive bookmark, moved by hand

Comment: Tried the local tagging approach. Works a treat. Is exactly the kind of marking I was after.

Comment: @LazyBadger: A bookmark would work too and give almost the same workflow. But I think a local tag has a slight advantage: tags don't move around (by design). Bookmarks can move, unless you avoid making them active. Also, local tags cannot be accidentally shared.